# How to install ROS Hydro but keep Groovy?

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had installed Hydro and Groovy at the same time in my system and was using them different workspaces.
Can someone help me un-installing Hydro and updating or keeping Groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187458/how-to-install-ros-hydro-but-keep-groovy?/) by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Can you add a few more specifics? What OS and version are you on? How did you install ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's assume your hydro workspace is `/home/username/workspace/ros_hydro/catkin`

If you have troubles with hydro interfering your groovy installation:

- edit your ~/.bashrc (if gedit is your editor of choice it'd be `gedit ~/.bashrc`) and remove lines such like `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` or `source /home/username/workspace/ros_hydro/catkin/devel/setup.bash`
- Now you still have a hydro installation and workspace around but it is no longer sourced so it will not be found by any ros command or build system. If you might whish to recover your hdyro system in the future this would be a good state.

If you **really** whish to completely uninstall ros hydro:

- delete your hydro workspace (using the assumption I'd be `cd /home/username/workspace/` and `rm -r ros_hydro`)
- all hydro apt packages are named ros-hydro-whatever-package. You can remove them all by `sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro*`. Likely a `sudo apt-get autoremove` will be needed after this....

(No warranties for last two steps;) )

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0